# Popup box asking users to register

Tags: user, popup

I'm looking for a Joomla 3 extension that requests new visitors to create an account in my site with a Popup.
I'd like to offer an e-book in exchange, so the popup should have an area to show how the e-book looks like and another area to register (or login, if the user already has an account).
If possible, this extension should also allow users to register/login using FB or Google.

I've seen many extensions but none that does exactly this.

Can someone please advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I'll combine two extensions: form builder and a tools to display a module in a modal

Start with the form builder like:

- Chronoform
- RS form
- or your preferred form tools.

See list of form extension : http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/forms

With the form you can collect the user data and send the e-book
Only one condition, this tools should provide you a module to display the form

Use an other extension to display the module in a modal
http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mod-modal-box

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be a good idea.
But, is the forum capable of registering the user (as in the core register form)?

Comment: yes, chronoform and RS form provide full Joomla registration